# How do I get rid of the error 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments' on my SwiftUI TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I'm trying to make a tab view in the app I'm making to learn SwiftUI but the problem is I get this error saying that I'm passing an argument to a function that takes no arguments. I'll show you my code, I really don't know what's going on and any help is appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("The First Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text("First")
                }
            Text("Another Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("Second")
                }
            Text("The Last Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
                    Text("Third")
                }
        }
        .font(.headline)
    }
}

struct TabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabView()
    }
}
```

I literally copy pasted this example from Apple's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name it something like `MyTabView` instead. "TabView" is reserved for SwiftUI's `TabView`.

```
struct MyTabView: View { /// here!
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            Text("The First Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text("First")
                }
            Text("Another Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("Second")
                }
            Text("The Last Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
                    Text("Third")
                }
        }
        .font(.headline)
    }
}

struct MyTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyTabView()
    }
}
```